# Get Current Sp parameters and values - (reflection alike)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Lets say I have this simple SP :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mySp
  @a int, 
  @b int
AS
  BEGIN
      ...
      ...
      select ________
  END
```

Now let's say I execute it via :

`exec mySp 1,2`

Question :

Is there **any** code which I can place in the `______` so it will show me :

```
"you sent param named a with value 1"
"you sent param named b with value 2"
```

This code should be **dynamic** (pasted in some SP's). Hence I can't do :

```
select "you sent param named a...with value "+cast (@a...)
select "you sent param named b...with value "+cast (@b...)
```

*(it has to read its context parameters and values at runtime)*

Is it possible ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, are you looking for SQL Server Profiler? This is the tool can trace all SP with parameters running on remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do it cleanly. One really dirty way of doing is to pass in an additional varchar column which is a comma separated list values of rest of the parameters. Then you can get the names of individual params and match them with the passed in parameter. Here's a sample

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mySp
  @a int, 
  @b INT,
  @c varchar(MAX)
AS
  BEGIN
  declare @names varchar(MAX) = ''
      SELECT @names += name +','
      FROM sys.parameters
      WHERE object_id = @@PROCID AND name <> '@c'
      ORDER BY parameter_id

      SELECT 'The passed in values for '+@names + ' are ' +@c

  END


go
EXEC mySp 1,1, '1,1'
```